# Error trying to download Github package on r

Tags: r, github

I am trying to download the package 'seegSDM' package but keep getting an error despite trying a couple different ways.

I am using Rx64 3.6.2 and have been using the package 'githubinstall' to try and download the package.

```
library(githubinstall)
gh_install_packages("seegSDM")
```

When I use this I get the error

```
"Error: unexpected string constant in:
"suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))
tools:::makeLazyLoading("seegSDM", "C:/Users/Laptop'"
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'seegSDM'
* removing 'C:/Users/Laptop/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/seegSDM'
Error: Failed to install 'seegSDM' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Laptop'~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpe6YLGi/file26b07cc06130/seegSDM_0.1-9.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
In addition: Warning message:
In fread(download_url, sep = "\t", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  :
  Found and resolved improper quoting out-of-sample. First healed line 4848: <<Puriney  honfleuR        "Evening, honfleuR" by Seurat>>. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
```

Any advice? I need to use the function neasrestLand so I can nudge points on a raster to the nearest land.

Comment: Does `install_github()` from package `remotes` work?

Answer (score 0):

It think you need to add the organization name (SEEG-Oxford). The package installs fine with

```
remotes::install_github("SEEG-Oxford/seegSDM"
```

and I suppose it might also work with

```
gh_install_packages("SEEG-Oxford/seegSDM")
```